# Cloud build can't open requirements.txt

Tags: google-cloud-platform, yaml, google-cloud-build

I want to setup a cloud build trigger so that each time I modify (commit and push) `main.py`, it execute `test_mainpytest.py` with `pytest`

I have a project that look like this :

```
My_Project\function_one\
                        main.py
                        deploy.yaml
                        requirements.txt
                        dir_pytest\
                                   test_mainpytest.py
```

My `deploy.yaml` contain thoose steps :

```
steps:
  - name: 'python'
    args: ['pip3', 'install', '-r', 'My_Project/function_one/requirements.txt', '--user']
  - name: 'python'
    args: ['python3', 'pytest', 'My_Project/function_one/dir_pytest/']
```

For the moment I just want to try to execute `pytest` using the trigger. When I execute the cloud build trigger, I get this error :

`ERROR: Could not open requirements file: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'My_Project/function_one/requirements.txt'`

Also my project is saved in a google cloud repository.

Edit :

I tried to add `dir` in my step, so it currently look like this :

```
steps:
  - name: 'python'
    dir: 'MyProject/function_one/'
    args: ['pip3', 'install', '-r', 'My_Project/function_one/requirements.txt', '--user']
  - name: 'python'
    dir: 'MyProject/function_one/'
    args: ['python3', 'pytest', 'My_Project/function_one/dir_pytest/']
```

Yet I still get the error, (I also tried to put `dir` after `args` but it didn't change much

I also noticed; when executing the trigger in Cloud Build; thoose 2 lines :

```
Initialized empty Git repository in /workspace/.git/
From https://source.developers.google.com/p/my_id_1234/r/My_Project
```

Should I use `https://source.developers.google.com/p/my_id_1234/r/My_Project` and add the path to my `requirement.txt` and my `py_test` directory ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could you show your whole cloudbuild.yaml? If you are using a build trigger, the repository is imported directly in /workspace. If you are doing a git clone, then your repository is inside a directory with the name of the repository. The difference is:

```
/workspace/my-repository/My_Project/function_one/requirements.txt
```

versus

```
/workspace/My_Project/function_one/requirements.txt
```

If nothing else works, you can do `ls -R` to show you the directory structure within the build. Add this as a first build step:

```
 - name: 'list recursively'
   args: ['ls', '-R']
```

Comment: This is my whole cloudbuild.yaml, I'm gonna try your solutions, thanks for trying to help me out !

Comment: Also change the slash backwards in slash forwards

Comment: Ahum, it might be a dumb question, but where do I enter the ls -R command ? I'm still learning GCP, 1st time using cloud build. I fixed the slash btw, didn't noticed I put them  wrong when creating my topic !

Comment: As a separate step, before the other steps. It lists the directory structure recursively. So from the output you can see if you are missing something.

Comment: Okay I added your step, and modified my dir, now it download the requirements ! Thank you, you helped me a lot !

Comment: wanted to add the step for ls-R but got during build `generic::invalid_argument: invalid build: invalid build step name "list recursively": could not parse reference: list recursively`

Answer (score 1):

Notice that Cloud Build uses a directory called `/workspace` as a working directory in order to persist the contents. You can add the [`dir` field](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/build-config#dir) within your cloudbuild.yaml file in order for Cloud Build to find the `requirements.txt` file and then run the tests.

Comment: That's right I didn't saw the ```/workspace``` directory ! Thanks for your answer, I'm going to try it out, brb !

Comment: So I tried to add "dir" in my step, currently it look like that : ```steps:
  - name: 'python'
    args: ['pip3', 'install', '-r', 'requirements.txt', '--user']
    dir: '`My_Project/function_one/'``` yet I still got the same error, am I missing something ?